# /bin/bash -s meaning (and also << EOT)

Tags: bash

What is the meaning of "-s" in the following command?

`ssh webapp@www.myserver.de /bin/bash -s << EOT`

(from https://forum.gitlab.com/t/better-way-for-multiline-ssh-command/23420)

I understand that the command open a SSH session and execute `/bin/bash` with/followed_by the "-s" argument/option.
Is this correct?

Furthermore, I think it says "execute the following script and it "pass << EOT" to say get all the following text/lines as the script code, it will end with an "EOT".
If the previous interpretation is correct EOT is End Of Transmission and can be any word (is just a label)?

Comment: When you ask for "meaning of" a command/a switch/etc. give a manual read with command `man ...`, that's in your case `man bash`

Comment: Sorry, I did but still was not clear to me and other documentation online just refer to "-" or "-i", plus with my question I wanted to know a little bit more. (also, initially I thought -s was an argument for ssh :-()

Comment: Also this information was important. Just share with us next time, so we (I) can better answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-s` option of a standard compliant shell tells the shell to read commands from stdin even if stdin is not connected to a tty.

In your case, the `here document` that follows in the script is used as stdin for the shell and that input is used as script to execute.